# What is the importance of the Kernel, Quotient Groups, and Cosets?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently taking a course in Abstract Algebra, and I am struggling to see the "big picture" or purpose of some of the topics we are studying. I know how to find the Kernel group, but I am unsure of what its purpose is. What does the Kernel subgroup tell you about groups, properties of groups, or applications in other areas of math. The same thing applies for Cosets and Quotient groups. Is them purpose to partition groups into sets that are easier to analyze/digest? I am struggling to relate these concepts to other areas of math and applications.

I would really appreciate any insight into this matter!

Thank you!

Comment: "kernel group" in the abstract does not exist. There is the kernel of a homomorphism, and its importance, as well as that of quotients and cosets, will be the subject of Noether's (First) Isomorphism Theorem. Frankly, you need to wait to see it.

Comment: Noether's Isomorphism Theorems are certainly the main motivation for these objects. Eventually you'll be building lattices of subgroups and relating them to field extensions. For cosets and quotients I would encourage you to examine $\mathbb{R}^3$ under addition. Here the cosets and quotients have a nice geometric interpretation so you can sketch it out to build intuition.